property accessory containing everything in javascript
I have this kind of javascript property.
currencies.EUR.name: "Euro" 

Between dot notation EUR could be something else like USD. With javascript how could I change that to something like this:
currencies.{every value}.name: "Euro"


Use bracket notation. See the duplicate.
